# How to remove event listener if callback is a parameterised arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where I want to remove the event listener.

```
    export const addEventToDropDown = (callback) => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
            if (event.key === "Backspace" && document.activeElement.type === "select-one") {
                event.target.value = "";
                callback(event);
            }
        }, true);

    }


    export const removeEventListner = () => {
        //document.removeEventListener("keydown");
    }
```

Comment: why dont you add the condition and remove event listener inside the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a handler dynamically and store a reference to it in a closure.
In this way it will be possible to deregister the handler using [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

```
const createKeydownHandler = callback => event => {
    if (event.key === "Backspace" && document.activeElement.type === "select-one") {
        event.target.value = "";
        callback(event);
    }
};

let keydownHandler;

export const addEventToDropDown = (callback) => {
    keydownHandler = createKeydownHandler(callback);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, true);
}

export const removeEventListner = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove an event listener if you have a reference to it.

Since you passed an arrow function to `addEventListener` directly (and didn't, for example, store it in a variable and then use that variable in the call to `addEventListener`) you don't have a reference to it.

Therefore: You can't.